# Get numeric position indicator on icons in taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, hotkeys

You can open/switch to applications on the taskbar using SUPER+. A great feature, but hard to use due to the fact you have to count the icons..

Is there a way to show the positions on these icons?

**Update: Keeping the accepted answer for history, but see later answer for software.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple solution: write the numbers on a piece of paper and tape it on your monitor next to the taskbar.

Comment: :) Oldschool, +1.

Comment: By “next”, you mean below?

You could also use write on a bit of clear tape and put it right *on* the screen, like an overlay.

Of course you have to beware that the taskbar can change easily in Windows 7. You can drag-and-drop the icons to re-arrange them, so you may find that the numbers you memorized are now incorrect. They also expand and shrink when you run a program, so an overlay might not work.

Comment: I did it your way. I feel so young again :)

Answer (score 6):

I tried the piece of paper method. But a pain if you move around several workstations.
Also tried using a Frameless image viewer to display a semi transparent image of a sequence of numbers. But this number sequence image has to be created for each display resolution.

Finally I found a software based solution that is freeware, small file size *(under 100K)* & portable *(unzip to install in any location):*

**7+ Taskbar Numberer**

http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-numberer

Comment: Looks really nice, but doesn't work in the classic Win 2000 theme.

Comment: Nice, thanks! I still have the piece of paper here :) It's also a pain when having more windows open as the icons shrink. I'll be sure to try this one.